# Как реализовать рандом в определенном диапазоне с "выколотым" числом, которое было в прошлой переменной с рандомом?

Tags: python

```
from random import randint
a1 = randint(1,100)
a2 = randint(1,100)
print(a1)
print(a2)
```

например, в `a1` будет `88`

тогда как в `a2` получить значение `от 1 до 100`, не включая число `88`

при этом используя только линейные алгоритмы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверен, что это то, что нужно, но как вариант:

```
from random import shuffle
l = list(range(1, 100))
shuffle(l)
print(l.pop(), l.pop())
```

Или без перемешивания:

```
from random import randint
l = list(range(1, 100))
print(l.pop(randint(1, len(l) - 1)))
print(l.pop(randint(1, len(l) - 1)))
```

Comment: автор говорит ему без циклов, а тут все таки неявно цикл есть

Comment: @Zhihar а где здесь цикл?

Comment: `list(range())` - это все таки неявный цикл по range с занесением в список, но если устраивает - то без проблем

Answer (score 1):

1. если числа целые и их не очень много, то

   ```
    res = random.choice(i for i in range(a, b + 1) if i != last)
   ```

т.е. формируем список значений в которые не включено ранее выбранное число `last` и выбираем случайно значение из сформированного списка

2. если же числа целые и их много, то практически без изменения распределения можно сделать так:

   ```
    res = last

    while res == last:
        res = random.randomint(a, b)
   ```

т.е. выбираем в непроколотом отрезке и если все таки попали на ранее выбранное значение, то выбираем еще раз

тут конечно немного меняется распределение, но из-а большого кол-ва значений очень несущественно, иначе см. способ 1)

3. если числа с плавающей запятой, то там вообще бессмысленно какие-то проколы учитывать - там в идеале все бесконечномалом должно быть

**P.S.**

для целых чисел есть еще один способ, который не изменит распределения совсем (наверное это идеальный способ)

```
value = random.randint(a, b - 1)

if value >= last:
    value += 1

if value == b + 1:
    value = a
```

т.е. выбираем число из диапазона [a, b) и если оно не меньше `last` просто сдвигаем на 1 вправо, т.е. как бы создаём прокол

надо только учесть если было выколото числа `last == b` - это случай можно обработать по разному - или в начале или в конце (как я)

Comment: а как без использования циклов вообще и для 7 переменных?

Comment: вы про пункт 2) ну сделайте тогда просто выбор следующего значения вправо если попали на текущее, опять же - при большом диапазоне распределение случайных чисел будет практически линейным

Comment: в 1) пункте тоже есть цикл

Comment: нужно для 7 переменных и без циклов ЛЮБЫХ, только линейными алгоритмами

Comment: ну тогда используйте п.2)
а почему циклы то не нравятся?

есть еще один способ - сейчас добавлю

Comment: почему не нравятся? нравятся, но в задании требуется без циклов

Comment: посмотрите последний способ *после P.S."

Answer (score 1):

Можно ещё через множества, хотя это в неявном виде всё-равно те же циклы. Но совсем в неявном.

```
from random import randint,choice
numbers = set(range(1,100))
a1 = choice(list(numbers))
numbers.remove(a1)
a2 = choice(list(numbers))
numbers.remove(a2)
a3 = choice(list(numbers))
# ...
print(a1)
print(a2)
print(a3)
# ...
```

И так можно и дальше продолжать.